# Cannot read property 'isVisible' of null Ext JS Treestore

Tags: extjs

Getting this error in Ext JS 6.5.3, I suspect it has something to do with the tree store defined here:

```
Ext.define('Company.view.reports.AdvancedTripsReportViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.advancedtripsreport',
    
    requires: [
        'Ext.data.Store',
        'Ext.data.TreeStore',
        'Company.model.AdvancedTripsReportRecord',
        'Company.model.AdvancedTripsReportTreeRecord'
    ],

    stores: {
        AdvancedTripsReportTreeGridStore: {
            type: 'tree',
            model: 'Company.model.AdvancedTripsReportTreeRecord',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                //root: 'Root'
            },
            rootVisible: false,
            storeId: 'advancedTripsReportTreeGridStore',
            remoteSort: true
        }
```

There was a bug defined in the Sencha forums here, but its unclear whether it was resolved or not: https://forum.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?468923-Race-Condition-in-TreeStore-setRoot

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar scenario but in my case i removed the beforeLoad event on the pagingtoolbar and the tree loaded successfully.